# How can I use Spring Security with my React-SpringBoot application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Little context to start off the question, I did the frontend in react with backend implementation in springboot.

While I develop, in package.json I set `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",` so that it can proxy my requests to localhost:8080 which is the spring's tomcat server.

For production, I use frontend-maven-plugin to build the react app and maven-antrun-plugin to copy the react production build to the backend directory(target/classes/public) and finally deploy to heroku.

After adding spring security to my project I realized it adds support for a login page on "/login" which I changed to "/my-login" by changing `http.loginPage()` as such

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
  http.authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/my-login")
      .permitAll(true)
      .and()
      .logout()
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/my-login?logout")
      .permitAll();
  http.cors();
```

Now the issue is my login page is inside the react app directory and I can't have another login page inside of spring boot directory. 
I tried having a .jsp login page as an intermediate which would talk with Spring Security and making a post request on it from react's side but couldn't really do anything with this approach.

So is there some other approach to have a login page being served from react which can still interface with spring security?

Thanks,

Paras

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same issue.  SpringBoot backend with Spring Security and React front-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just getting started with spring ...but generally with React applications, authentication is stateless...we set the Authorization header that contains a token (for Eg: jwt) and we have a logout endpoint that invalidates the token. So a 200 on the logout request = "/my-login?logout". And a 403 in any routes are redirected by the "Client side" router to "/my-login"

The approach you have taken requires the View to be "Server side" rendered..and React SSR (Server side rendering) as far as I know, is exclusive to a NodeJS server.

[Link to a "JWT authentication with spring" article](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-security/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-authentication-architecture-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Reactjs does client side rendering as it is a Javascript library, whereas if you use springboot for backend, you will have to make jsp pages which does server side rendering. They both generally do not complement each other. For react apps, you should generally make a REST API as the backend and render the changes in webpage based on the response.

Now if you are sure that you only want a spring boot app as backend, you will have to convert the login html page in react to jsp page of springboot and render your component there. On login success, you will redirect the users to another jsp page which will render your entire react app.

So basically your react and spring boot apps wont run on different ports and will be combined into single spring boot application.

Comment: I know this is old, but can you point me to some examples of how the JSP page would render the react app, once the user is authenticated?  I.e., probably on Login success, user would be routed to the React /home page

Comment: @PeterKronenberg There wont be a react page. E.g. If you create your react app, build it and you will get the Js code. Now serve that Js code in your JSP file. So basically you dont have to deal with react once built. You work with JSP normally.